# IE vs.Chrome CSS priority

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

When I apply the following css file to a page in IE:

```
@import url("reset.css");

body {
    background-color:gray;
    background-image: url(“../images/bg-body.jpg”);
}
```

I get a background image. When I view the page in Chrome I get a gray background. Is there some difference in the style priorities between browsers?

Comment: Can you provide your code through fiddle or codepen.

Comment: Strange. I tried it again now and Chrome is showing the bg image.

Comment: images are always rendered before color, i guess you can call it top priority. what mattered may be because your quotes are wrong. it's `"` and not `“` or `”`. also, you don't put quotes inside `url()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this:

```
body {background-color:gray; background-image: url(../images/bg-body.jpg)}
```

You got 2 places wrong, it's `"` and not `“` or `”`. Also, there shouldn't be quotes inside `url()`.

Browsers should always display images before color, if you want only color to be displayed, you should only be able to do it with:

```
body {background-image:none}
```

Comment: Actually it was the quotes that were causing my problem